# Struggling to convert VMware ESX Hosts to Hyper-V

Tags: vmware-esx, scvmm

I've been struggling to convert a VMWare ESX Server to Hyper-V now for a couple of days. I've tried MVMC 3.1 without success, and are trying SCVMM to do it, but I've run into a wall again.

MVMC 3.1 fails the moment it starts converting the disk, I'm not sure why.

SCVMM are complaining about disk space now. I'm not sure why SCVMM want to convert the VM onto my C drive on the Hyper-V box. Is there some way you can specify where the VHD should be created?

I further struggle to get the VMWare cluster Host status out of OK (Limited). I've done all the documentation said, but some credentials is incorrect. Should the `RUN AS` User be the same as what I've used to Add the VMWare server to SCVMM? Because for some reason that does not work, or should it be the Linux credentials?

I've downloaded the eval version VHD of SCVMM 2012 R2 (running on Windows 2012 R2 Eval of course). The VMWare host is running version 5.

Hope anyone can help me, because my google searches does not really help me (I might not use the correct phrases)

**UPDATE**

The error that I get with MCMV is `The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Accelerators.Mvmc.Engine.EnigeObjectResolver' threw an exception`

It is looking for an assembly named `System.Management.Automation`. I've installed MVMC from scratch on the server, so I'm not sure why it is looking for it.

**UPDATE 2**

I've found that for MVMC I need Powershell 3.0 (or the Windows Management Framework 3.0). I've downloaded and installed it, restarted the server, and now it seems to work. I still struggle with SCVMM though

**UPDATE 3**

MVMC run for just over 2 hours and fell over saying that a connection was closed unexpectedly. I'm going to try the sysinternals idea this weekend. Hopefully that will work. :(

Answer (score 2):

You should see this screen in the MVMC for the destination path for the converted VM. Create a shared folder on your desired storage location and select it in the conversion wizard.

[image]

Comment: my problem is not as much with the MVMC as with SCVMM. All of what you explained I can do but it fails the moment it starts to convert the drive. Last time I've tried to put in a path other than the target server (To a NAS drive) it gave me some issue that it should be on the same machine. I'm just cloning the VM at the moment, then I will try again.

Comment: Is the storage location you are choosing available to the target host?

Comment: I've updated my question. However the convertion fail now every time about 2h10m in with a message saying that the connection was closed unexpectedly. These MS tools always have some issue

Answer (score 1):

You may try **Starwind V2V Converter**

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter

Comment: You have to point to the actual VMWare VMDK?

Answer (score 0):

For some workloads, I use the sysinternals tool disk2vhd.  Stop all required services first, and you can perform the migration with a powered on virtual machine and avoid copying two times the disk as some solutions do.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

SysInternals (Microsoft now) Disk2VHD.  I can't afford SCVMM so this tool was invaluable when migrating from P2V

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656415.aspx

(you run it from inside the booted VM, saved the created VHD file somewhere, and then create a new Hyper-V VM from scratch, pointed to the VHD that was created by Disk2VHD)